# Markdown Mail Button Laravel not working correctly

Tags: css, laravel, email

I have created the following markdown mail in laravel:

```
@component('mail::message')
@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Button Text
@endcomponent
Thanks,<br>
@endcomponent
```

What I end up receiving when I send this mail is the following:
[image]

The button is put over the end of the mailfile, even though I do close the component. Any ideas? I did not alter the mail:message / mail:button template.

Answer (score 1):

Edit Notification class like this code

```
 public function toMail($notification)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('')
        ->action('Thanks', url('add your custom link'));
}
```

Comment: But that does not solve the problem of the button not loading correctly, right?